# React Native Maps , components below map are displayed above map and not below it

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-maps

I am trying react native maps and i want to display text field and other components below map, but all components are displayed above map

ContactComponent - (Where i am using map component and below it want to display other components)

```
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MapComponent />
        <Text>Akas</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

MapComponent -

```
    render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MapView
          provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE} // remove if not using Google Maps
          style={styles.map}
          initialRegion={{
            latitude: 19.15384,
            longitude: 72.92902,
            latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
            longitudeDelta: 0.0421
          }}
        >
          <Marker
            coordinate={{
              latitude: 19.15384,
              longitude: 72.92902
            }}
            title={"Hello"}
            description={"desc"}
          />
        </MapView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    justifyContent: "flex-end",
    alignItems: "center"
  },
  map: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject` is basicaly same as :

```
position:absolute,
top: 0,
left: 0,
...
```

When component is absolute positioned it is detached from normal flow of layout (as it is in css), so try not to use it for map. Instead use `flex:1,` or `width: 100%`, etc.